# Flutter - How to fix dynamic widgets that are not loading on page load?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am creating a flutter app and created a page that pulls data from a sqlite database and load a widget dynamically that displays the data from the sqlite db when the page loads. For some reason, the widgets are not loading. It only loads the dynamic widgets in debug mode when I hot reload the app.

Here is my code:

```
Users userList = new Users();
List details = new List<Widget>();
var db = new DB_Helper();

_addToUserList(Map<dynamic, dynamic> json)
{
    userList.membersList.add(json);
    return userList.membersList;
}

  List<Widget> getTeamMembers()
   { 
    // Get data from db
   db.getMembers().then((data) {
      // clear list to prevent repeating if page refreshes
      userList.membersList.clear();
      details.clear();
      for (Members m  in data)
      {
        Map<String, dynamic> json;
        json = 
        {
          "member_id": m.memberId,
          "member_name": m.memberName,
          "member_email": m.memberEmail
        };
        _addToUserList(json);
      }

       for (Map<dynamic, dynamic> u in userList.membersList) {
        Map<String, dynamic> js = u;
        var emailCtrl = new TextEditingController();
        var name = js["member_name"];
        emailCtrl.text = js["member_email"];

      details.add(

         new Card(
           color: Colors.blue,
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(2),
          child: ExpansionTile(
            title: Text(name),
            children: <Widget>[
               Row(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                    Expanded(
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[

                       Container(
                         width: 280,
                         padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                         margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                         child: TextField(
                           enabled: false,
                           controller: emailCtrl,
                           style: TextStyle(color: Colors.purple),
                           decoration: InputDecoration(
                             labelText: "EMAIL:",
                             labelStyle: new TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                             border: InputBorder.none,
                           ),
                         ),
                       ),

                      ],
                    ),
                      ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),                          
      );    
       }

    });

    return details;  
  }
```

I have tried fetching the data and storing it in a list in initState(), but the page still loads blank.

I have tried to use await when querying sqlite but it throws an error inside the  scaffold body property where I call the widget.

The only time it loads properly, is when I remove the code that queries the db and hard code the userList with values rather than pull it out from sqlite. Querying sqlite db seems to be preventing the widgets from displaying. How can I pull data out from sqlite and add it to a dynamic widget to display on page loads?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is definitely kind of a mess.

You should you use a `ListView.builder` instead. You should NOT use any Dart for loops for building your Widgets. Simply have your array of data properly setup and use the ListView.builder to build the Cards and other Widgets. Here is an example of using `ListView.builder`:

```
ListView.builder(
          itemCount: list.length,
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int i) {
            return Dismissible(
              key: ObjectKey(list[i]),
              background: Container(
                alignment: AlignmentDirectional.centerEnd,
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 10.0, 0.0),
                  child: Icon(
                    Icons.delete,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              confirmDismiss: (direction) async {
                if (direction == DismissDirection.startToEnd) {
                  /// edit item
                  return false;
                } else if (direction == DismissDirection.endToStart) {
                  /// delete
                  return true;
                }
              },
              onDismissed: (direction) {
                setState(() {
                  var paymentMethod = list[i];
                  list.removeAt(i);
                  _showDeletePaymentDialog(paymentMethod);
                });
              },
              child: Card(
                color: BmsColors.primaryBackgroundColor,
                elevation: 2.0,
                child: ListTile(
                  title: Text(
                    'xxxx-${list[i].last4}',
                    style: UIUtil.getTxtStyleCaption(),
                  ),
                  subtitle: Text(
                    list[i].brandDisplay,
                    style: UIUtil.getTxtStyleCaption(),
                  ),
                  leading: CardUtils.getCardIcon(list[i].brand),
                  trailing: (list[i].isDefault)
                      ? Icon(
                          Icons.check_circle,
                          size: 32,
                          color: BmsColors.primaryForegroundColor,
                        )
                      : Container(
                          width: 32,
                        ),
                  onTap: () {
                    debugPrint('Tapped on ');
                  },
                ),
              ),
            );
          },
        ),
```

You should also be using a `FutureBuilder` for your async call to get data:

```
 FutureBuilder(
    future: _getDataFromDatabase(), //async function that returns a Future<Map<String, dynamic>>
    builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          list = [];
        }
        return CircularProgressIndicator();
      }

      list = snapshot.data;
      return _buildScaffold(); //contains your ListView.builder
    });
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the feedback, I will try these out and do further research on FutureBuilder and ListView.builder for a better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Brian's answer has a lot of things you should consider. Though there's one part of your question that I think needs some attention:

> It only loads the dynamic widgets in debug mode when I hot reload the
>   app.

This is pretty much always indicative that you're missing a setState((){}) call once there is a change in data. It means that there was a change but the UI has not been rebuilt after the change has occurred. Even with Brian's alterations you don't have a setState called (though if you're only adding this data once at page load then this isn't an issue so much). Certainly use Brian's suggestions for how to build your UI. ListView.builder is the way to go for these types of needs. My answer is more-so something to consider in the future when you make changes to data and don't see any changes reflected in your UI.